# Cleaner way to save foreign key relationship in django

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys, modelform

I am currently doing the following and was wondering if there's any way to condense these 4 lines...as they're very verbose....

```
g = game_form.save(commit=False)
team = Team.objects.get(pk=team_id)
g.team = team
g.save()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's ok for `Team` to be part of the form then I would make `Team` a [ModelChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield) in my form. Django will handle everything behind the scenes for you.

Comment: Team is already being passed in so we actually dont want to have the user input it again, a second time.